# Module '"mongoose"' has no exported member 'CreateQuery'

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I am doing this

`import { CreateQuery, FilterQuery, QueryFindBaseOptions } from 'mongoose';`

and I receive following errors:

```
Module '"mongoose"' has no exported member 'CreateQuery'.
Module '"mongoose"' has no exported member 'QueryFindBaseOptions'.
```

I tried with `npm i @types/mongoose` but the problem was not solved.
I also saw [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mongoose) that the package above is no longer needed since 3rd june 2021 because `Mongoose publishes its own types, so you do not need to install this package.`

What is the solution for fixing this error?

Comment: I have not used mongoose, but can surely help you out. Could you please tell used where `CreateQuery` is used? I mean where do you pass this method/variable

Comment: If you dig into the source code, you will see that there's no `CreateQuery` or `QueryFindBaseOptions ` exported. Where do you find these variables?

Comment: @AmirSaleem and Cuong, I was following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/TbT7eO1fxuI?t=599

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok refer to the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TbT7eO1fxuI&t=599s) you are following, it uses `"@types/mongoose": "^5.10.5"` and since this video was published on 28/5/2021 so the version `5.10.5` will be used for `@types/mongoose`. That's why `CreateQuery` and `QueryFindBaseOptions` can be used. But `@types/mongoose` released version `5.11` on 03/06/2021 so this version will be chosen when you follow the tutorial but there is nothing exported with version `5.11`.

If you still want to follow the tutorial, you can use version `5.10.5` for `@types/mongoose` by specify `"@types/mongoose": "5.10.5"` in `package.json`.

Comment: For those who want the exact command: `npm i @types/mongoose@5.10.5 -D`